# NoClassDefFoundError while installing Mondrian on Mac

Tags: macos, mondrian

I am trying to install Mondrian on my Mac OS X. I am facing the below error at step 12 of [this guide](http://tinyurl.com/9y4f8aa)

Command is as below :-

```
java -cp “/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/mondrian/WEB-INF/lib/mondrian.jar: /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/mondrian/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.9.jar: /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/mondrian/WEB-INF/lib/eigenbase-xom.jar: /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/mondrian/WEB-INF/lib/eigenbase-resgen.jar: /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/mondrian/WEB-INF/lib/eigenbase-properties.jar: /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/mondrian/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.5-bin.jar” mondrian.test.loader.MondrianFoodMartLoader -verbose -tables -data -indexes -jdbcDrivers=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver -inputFile=/usr/local/mondrian/demo/FoodMartCreateData.sql -outputJdbcURL=”jdbc:mysql://localhost/foodmart?user=foodmart&password=foodmart”
```

The error is as below :-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/mondrian/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1/2/9/jar:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .usr.local.tomcat.webapps.mondrian.WEB-INF.lib.log4j-1.2.9.jar:
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Comment: i've never used mondrian by itself. You can use pentaho BI server which is a integrated solution with all you need to run mondrian alog side with jpivot etc. http://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Business%20Intelligence%20Server/4.5.0-stable/

Answer (score 0):

Do you have log4j jar in your /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/mondrian/WEB-INF/lib/ folder? Cause the class loader id not able to find log4j that you have mentioned in your class path.